# Spring @Value variable not logging as expected

Tags: java, spring

I have declared a String using Springs @Value annotation as follows:

```
@Value("${blah.blah.authKey}")
private String authorizationKey;
```

I would expect that if this property is correctly defined in a .properties file - then I should be able to logger.trace() this variable to see its injected value.  But for some reason:

```
logger.trace("Bearer Authorization header: " + authorizationKey);
```

Outputs: **${blah.blah.authKey}**
 whereas

```
logger.trace("Bearer Authorization header: " + this.authorizationKey);
```

Outputs: ***Bearer actual-key-value*** from the property file injection.

Why is there a difference in these logger statements?

Here is the code for the containing Java class.

```
package com.tsgrp.opencontent.allstate.leela.sharedecon.service;

... imports. . .

public class SeLeelaService implements ILeelaService {
   public static RestTemplate rt = new RestTemplate();

    @Value("${blah.blah.authKey}")
    private String authorizationKey;

    public LeelaWrapper getLeelaInfo(String claimNumber, String ticket) {
       String paddedClaimNumber = AllstateClaimsUtil.zeroPadClaim(claimNumber, 12);
        String queryJson = "query-here"
        String claimNumJson = "\"variables\":{\"claimNumber\":\""+paddedClaimNumber+"\"}";
        String finalBodyStr = queryJson.concat(claimNumJson);
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        SeLeelaClaimInfo claimInfo;
        SharedEconomyClaimWrapper seClaimWrapper;
        LeelaWrapper claimWrapper = null;
        try {
            CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.createDefault();
            HttpPost claimReq = new HttpPost(graphQlUrl);
            // add headers
            claimReq.addHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json");
            claimReq.addHeader("Accept","application/json");
            logger.trace("Bearer Authorization header: " + authorizationKey);
            claimReq.addHeader(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, authorizationKey);
. . .
. . .
. . .
```

There is only one . . . instance . . . of this instance variable here - why wouldn't the value be used in either logger statement? (This is log4j2 if that matters)

Comment: Did you annotated your `SeLeelaService` class with `@Configuration` annotation?

Comment: your class SeLeelaService is not a Spring bean

Comment: Side note: don't use field injection (`@Value` on a field is field injection).

Comment: Both `this.authorizationKey` and `authorizationKey` in this source code would be compiled to the exact same bytecode. The problem is elsewhere.

Comment: To those posting that the class is not annotated with `@Configuration`: `@Service` would be more appropriate given the name on the class. Furthermore, the annotation is superfluous if the interface is annotated.

Comment: What would adding @Service do here? I only need this value in this class - I am more just curious why the log file is not producing a real value either way.

Comment: @LoganLaFollette It makes, among other things, this class to a Spring-managed bean, and thus subject to injection/autowiring.

Answer (score 0):

The @Value annotation has not been scanned by Spring container.

If you are using Spring annotations like [@Value](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Value.html), [@Autowired](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Autowired.html) or [Jakarta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jakarta_Project)(the new name for the Java Enterprise Edition) annotations like [@PostConstruct](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/platform/8/apidocs/javax/annotation/PostConstruct.html), [@PreDestroy](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/platform/8/apidocs/javax/annotation/PreDestroy.html), then you need to add bean with these annotations to spring context. It makes container-managed bean. This allows the container to intercept the creation, scan all of these annotations and apply them.

You can add the bean to the context in many different ways. But usually, if you use annotations, then the whole configuration will be through annotations.
So just add one of these annotations: `@Component/@Service/@Repository/@Controller`

For your case, you need `@Service` annotation